# How does vim terminal talk to the root terminal emulator?

Tags: terminal

I use `vterm` to denote `terminal inside vim`, `rterm` to denote `root terminal emulator` in this post:

```
rterm--->vim--->vterm
```

**Question1**

All rendition is done by `rterm`? All escape sequence and text must be sent to `rterm`?

**Question2**

How does `vterm` talk to `rterm`? If I issue an escape sequence from `vterm`, how doe it get to `rterm`?

1. directly:  `vterm ===> rterm`
2. through vim: `vterm ===> vim ===> rterm`. If this is true, do we have [passthrough escape sequence](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-passthrough-escape-sequence-and-how-do-i-use-it)?

FWIW, I noticed that `\e[6 q`  (change cursor to bar, sent from `vterm`) works if `rterm` is `gnome-terminal`, `xterm`  or `urxvt`, but not for `st`.

**Question3**

How will things change If I use `tmux`?

```
rterm--->tmux--->vim--->vterm
```

Comment: Well, I think tmux is using a pseudo-tty+ncurses-style drawing (although ps reports regular ttys on my machine, so unclear). Vim also uses curses I believe... and it’s only terminal seems to be an xterm-ish emulator. For more we will need the devs

Comment: *FWIW, I noticed that \e[6 q (change cursor to bar, sent from vterm) works if rterm is gnome-terminal, xterm or urxvt, but not for st.*  It can work in st, and it can fail in gnome-terminal or in urxvt.  What matters is not the identity of the host/outer terminal.  What matters is `$TERM`.  Try this in st:  `TERM=xterm vim -Nu NONE +'term' +'call term_sendkeys("", "printf \"\\e[6 q\"\<cr>")'`.  It works as long as `$TERM` is `xterm` or a derivative (and maybe other values for which Vim thinks it's ok to relay the sequence).  Also, you obviously need the host terminal to support the sequence.

Comment: In case it helps, see also [this short comment](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/5887#issuecomment-609437491).

Comment: @user938271 Indeed, `\e[6 q` works for st if I chagne `TERM` to `xterm-16color`, I think this is a workaround, I'm not sure if it's practical, as I've been told many times that change TERM is a bad idea. Thanks for the link, it definitely helps.